# Is there a way I can Auto scroll to new message in a chat App I designed using flutter

Tags: flutter

I've tired the example in pub.dev and I've checked online for help but I'm new to flutter development so I don't know if it's not working because I'm not on the right track or because I've to tailored it to fit my specific code.

This is my code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:scroll_to_index/scroll_to_index.dart';
import 'package:chat_app_tutorial/helper/constants.dart';
import 'package:chat_app_tutorial/services/database.dart';
import 'package:chat_app_tutorial/widgets/widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ConversationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String chatRoomId;
  ConversationScreen(this.chatRoomId);

  @override
  _ConversationScreenState createState() => _ConversationScreenState();
}

class _ConversationScreenState extends State<ConversationScreen> {

  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  TextEditingController messagesController =new TextEditingController();
  ScrollController _controller = new ScrollController();

  Stream ChatMessageStream;



  Widget ChatMessageList(){
    final scrollDirection = Axis.vertical;
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: ChatMessageStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        return snapshot.hasData ? ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
            controller: _controller,
            children: ChatMessageStream.map<Widget>((data) {
              final index = data[0];
              final height = data[1];
              return AutoScrollTag(
                key: ValueKey(index),
                controller: _controller,
                index: index,
                child: Text('index: $index, height: $height'),
                highlightColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
              );
            }).toList(),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return MessageTile(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["message"], snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["sentBy"] == Constants.myName);
            }
        ) : Container();
      },
    );
  }

  sendMessage(){
    if(messagesController.text.isNotEmpty){
      Map<String, dynamic> messageMap = {
        "message" : messagesController.text,
        "sentBy" : Constants.myName,
        "time" : DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch
      };
      databaseMethods.saveConversationMessages(widget.chatRoomId, messageMap);
      messagesController.text = "";

      Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              () => _controller.jumpTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent));
    }

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    databaseMethods.getConversationMessages(widget.chatRoomId).then((value){
      setState(() {
        ChatMessageStream = value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBarMain(context),
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            ChatMessageList(),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                color: Color(0x54ffffff),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 16),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: messagesController,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "Type here",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white54
                            ),
                            border: InputBorder.none
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: (){
                        sendMessage();
                        Timer(
                            Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                                () => _controller
                                .jumpTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent));
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          height: 40,
                          width: 40,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    const Color(0x36ffffff),
                                    const Color(0x0fffffff)
                                  ]
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40)
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                          child: Image.asset("assets/images/send.png")
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessageTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String message;
  final bool isSentByMe;
  MessageTile(this.message, this.isSentByMe);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: isSentByMe?0:24, right: isSentByMe?24:0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      alignment: isSentByMe ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24, vertical: 8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: isSentByMe ? [
              const Color(0xff007EF4),
              const Color(0xff2A75BC)
            ]
                : [
              const Color(0x1AFFFFFF),
              const Color(0x1AFFFFFF)
            ],
          ),
          borderRadius: isSentByMe ? BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(23),
            topRight: Radius.circular(23),
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(23)
        )  :
        BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(23),
            topRight: Radius.circular(23),
            bottomRight: Radius.circular(23)
    ),
        ),
        child: Text(message, style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 17
        ),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I apologize if it's something I'm supposed to know, I'm still learning. If someone can just put me on the right path, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if i misunderstood the question, but basically you need to call

```
_controller.animateTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
```

you could either place this inside your code right under sendMessage inside a

```
SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
});
```

so that way it waits until the ChatMessageList has been rebuilt. Or alternatively you could place it inside this section and use a previousLength variable to check if the data has changed.

```
children: ChatMessageStream.map<Widget>((data) {
   if (previousLength != data.length)
   {
      _controller.animateTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);

      previousLength = data.length
   }
}
```

You might also have to place the animateTo here inside a SchedulerBinding or a Timer delay, considering the new ChatMessageList hasn't been fully built yet either